# Can't get the select option value into jQuery post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

HTML:

```
<select id="s2_basic" class="form-control" id="userid" name="userid">
    <option value="" selected>-- Choose option --</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function submitForm() {
    var userid = $('#userid').attr('selected', 'selected');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: "userid=" + userid,
        success: function(text) {
            if (text == "success") {
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Submit PHP returns error message:

```
Value: ([object Object])
```

I have also tried

```
var userid = $('#userid').val();
var userid = $('#userid option').val();
```

Still, the option value never gets passed correctly.
What am I doing wrong?

I want just the value="x" number to be posted as userid=x.

Comment: why do you have two ids there in your select ? id="s2_basic" and  id="userid" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove `id="s2_basic"` from your select.

change :

```
<select id="s2_basic" class="form-control" id="userid" name="userid">
```

to

```
<select class="form-control" id="userid" name="userid">
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#userid').on('change',function(){

console.log('value '+$('#userid option:selected').val())
console.log('text '+$('#userid option:selected').text())
console.log('index '+$('#userid option:selected').index())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="userid" name="userid">
    <option value="" selected>-- Choose option --</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

try this